# Wrong google_conversion_value via Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

In the JS bellow we cast a value, for instance, € 12,00 to a number 12. It also works for € 12,50 which becomes 12.5 or invalid numbers then it would return 0.

So as far as I can tell `conversionValue` should have a proper number as value. However, Google tag assistant keeps telling *"Dynamic conversion value in wrong format."*

```
var conversionValue = formatEuroToNumber('€ 12,00');

console.log('Conversion value: ' + conversionValue);

var google_conversion_id = 9999999;
var google_conversion_language = "nl";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "Someproduct";
var google_conversion_value = conversionValue;
var google_conversion_currency = 'EUR';
var google_remarketing_only = false;
```

Console output on formatEuroToNumber:

```
formatEuroToNumber('{factuur_bedrag}'); // 0
formatEuroToNumber('€ 12'); // 12
formatEuroToNumber('€ 12,00'); // 12
formatEuroToNumber('€ 12.00'); // 12
formatEuroToNumber('€ 12.5'); // 12.5
formatEuroToNumber('€ 12,5'); // 12.5
```

Comment: What "format" does it expect? I don't think it's talking about types here.

Comment: tag assistant can be a little buggy sometimes. I would just check the actual network request (search for the word "conversion" in the network tab) and check the actual query parameters. If you see conversion values being reported in AdWords, then you can ignore the tag assistant messages.